# Can we use multiple text color for same textbox?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have `<input />` from react side I'm receving it's value eg. DD/MM/YYYY
If User Start typing It Get's converted to 34/MM/YYYY

can I change color of MM/YYYY to some other diffrent color.

My Input Box -->

```
 <input name="newDate" id="newdate" label="New Date" 
  placeholder="ENTER DATE OF BIRTH IN DD/MM/YY FORMART" value="12/31/32YY">
```

Comment: directly... no, you can't, you would need to write some wrapper

Comment: please guide Thank you very much

Comment: I'm really busy right now, so I won't write a code for you, but a tip: use `<div contenteditable="true"></div>` instead of `input`, then you can assign a function that wraps the given parts of text in `spans` with a given style.